# Pinch to zoom in Visual Studio 2012 IDE (code view) not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, touch, multi-touch, gestures, pinchzoom

so I mean just the code viewer window thing! (even spent 15 minutes trying to figure out what that window is called, no result) NOT in designer view, simulation etc.

Perhaps best illustrated by an example:
When I try to use my touchscreen to scroll or pinch to zoom to show a colleague the part of code he's interested in it simply responds as if it were a mouse. (highlighting text)

Every Office 2013 application has sublime integration, but for vs2012 there doesn't even appear to be a plugin to add the support?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Neither Visual Studio 2012 nor Visual Studio 2013 support touch beyond the very basic support Windows provides for legacy applications.

The [VSCommands Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece) however does make things slightly more touch-friendly - not quite what you were asking for, though.

Comment: Please note that the vscommands extension is not free http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/purchase visual studio 2015 will have touch support and will have a community edition.

Comment: @JPHellemons Not exactly. VSCommands has 2 versions, Lite and Pro. Lite is free and includes the touch support described in my answer. However strictly speaking they ask that you pay for Pro for commercial projects. http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/compare-features